# Need to find eigenvectors in pyspark for a non-symmetric square matrix through eigen value decomposition similar to scipy.linalg.eig

Tags: python, scipy, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, eigenvector

I am a beginner so please correct me if I go wrong somewhere.

I have a square matrix of size 1 million x 1 million.
 I want to find the eigenvectors for it in pyspark. I know computeSVD gives me eigenvectors but those are through SVD and the result is a Dense Matrix which is a local data structure. I want the results which scipy.linalg.eig would give.

I saw there is a function EigenValueDecomposition using ARPACK in java and scala api for spark. Will it give same eigenvectors as eig in scipy? If yes, is there any way I can use it in pyspark? Or is there any alternate solution for the same. Can I use ARPACK directly in my code somehow or will I have to code Arnoldi iteration(for example) on my own?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried scipy.linalg.eig inside pyspark ? i think it will work.

Comment: @RishikeshTeke the problem is the entire matrix is not able to exist on driver node and goes out of memory. so i need something in distributed manner.

Comment: I found this in Pyspark doc it may help : For dense vectors, MLlib uses the NumPy array type, so you can simply pass NumPy arrays around. For sparse vectors, users can construct a SparseVector object from MLlib or pass SciPy scipy.sparse column vectors if SciPy is available in their environment. and on dense matrix there is toArray method which will convert it into ndArray which u can feed to scipy.linalg.eig

Comment: @RishikeshTeke thanks for the help. The issue is I cannot use numpy arrays because it wont fit in the driver memory. I need to perform the entire operation in distributed matrices only. I need a similar function to scipy.linalg.eig in spark which will run in distributed manner and NOT on driver using local data structures such as numpy arrays.

Comment: I'd recommend in this case the SciPy's wrapper for ARPACK [`scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html)

Comment: @SaulloCastro I do not have enough memory to compute it on python. Any solution in spark please?

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a python code to get a scipy sparse matrix and create a RowMatrix as the input to the computeSVD.
This is the part you need to convert the csr_matrix to list of SparseVectors. I use the parallel version since the sequential version is much slower and it is easy to make it parallel.

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame


num_row, num_col = fullMatrix.shape
lst_total = [None] * num_row
selected_indices = [i for i in range(num_row)]

def addMllibSparseVector(idx):
    curr = fullMatrix.getrow(idx)
    arr_ind = np.argsort(curr.indices)
    lst_total[idx] = (idx, SparseVector(num_col\
                 , curr.indices[arr_ind], curr.data[arr_ind]),)
pool = ThreadPool() 
pool.map(addMllibSparseVector, selected_indices)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Then I create the dataframes using below code.

```
import math
lst_dfs = []
batch_size = 5000
num_range = math.ceil(num_row / batch_size)

lst_dfs = [None] * num_range
selected_dataframes = [i for i in range(num_range)]

def makeDataframes(idx):
    start = idx * batch_size
    end = min(start + batch_size, num_row)
    lst_dfs[idx] = sqlContext.createDataFrame(lst_total[start:end]\
        , ["id", "features"])            
pool = ThreadPool() 
pool.map(makeDataframes, selected_dataframes)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Then I reduce them to 1 dataframe and create the RowMatrix.

```
raw_df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll,*lst_dfs)
raw_rdd = raw_df.select('features').rdd.map(list)
raw_rdd.cache() 
mat = RowMatrix(raw_rdd)
svd = mat.computeSVD(100, computeU=True)
```

I simplified the code and haven't tested it completely. Please feel free to comment if something has problem.